# iOS SearchBar mail effect

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I'd like to implement the feature shown in the image below to my application. The effect that I'd like to obtain is the same of the highlight of the "WebDeBs" string, it seems that only the iOS mail app does this, and I can't find anyone that tried to implement this.

Is there anyone that can give me some hint on how to reproduce this effect?

[image]

Comment: "no one ever tried to implement something like this." Well I doubt that. 
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=token

Comment: @AdilSoomro indeed it was best to say that I could not find anything... Thanks I'll give it a look...

Comment: did you found any solution for above ui?